# Ionic and ssh2: Error: process.binding not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to learn Ionic and I am attempting to create a simple application that uses SSH2 to establish an ssh connection between application and server. The following are the steps that I did in order to get the problem:

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create application: ionic start app_name tabs
2. cd to app_name directory
3. npm install --save ssh2
4. open project, go to any page (e.g. home.ts) and import ssh2 from 'ssh2';
5. Inside constructor type: console.dir(ssh2); Run ionic serve
6. Get **Error: Cannot find module: dns** and solved by adding **dns: 'empty'** to **/config/webpack.config.js**
7. Run application again and get **Error: process.binding is not supported**

I am using the following:

Ionic Framework: 3.9.2

Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.10

Angular Core: 5.2.11

Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11

Node: 8.11.2

OS Platform: Windows 10

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799888/can-you-use-the-node-package-ssh2-in-a-browser is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Suraj! It seems like ssh2 is written only for node.js

[Can you use the node package ssh2 in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799888/can-you-use-the-node-package-ssh2-in-a-browser)